# Is it possible to remove (Actions) and (Derived) from the QGIS Identify dialog?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

When identifying a layer in QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour, the Identify Results dialog shows (Actions) and (Derived) keywords:

[image]

Is it possible to remove these?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus I'm delivering a QGIS project to a non-technical user, and I'm trying to remove as much distracting and extraneous stuff from the UI as I can. For this project, there will be no Actions and the exact XY is unimportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

under the wrench icon in the identify features pop up, there is now an option to hide derived attributes from results & to hide null attributes from results.[image]

Comment: 9 years later and I have my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the identify view by the form view, when you select just one feature with the identify tool. It provides a view with only the feature's attributes. The form is read only, if the layer is not in editing mode.

[image: form view]

This option can be set in the options dialog *Settings > Options > Map tools*, Identify section. 
You should tick *Open feature form*, if a single feature is identified option.

Another option (Python knowledge is required) is to write a small plugin to show only what you want, the way you want. The following link might help: http://3nids.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/identify-feature-on-map/

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3x you can play between the major panel of the "Identify Results" option. The key option here is toggling off the "Expand New Results by Default". The feature form can be also opened from this panel as shown below.

[image]